# How to do a cf push from python script?

Tags: python, cloud-foundry

I am new to Cloud foundry. Here is the use case which I want to achieve,

I want to write a python script, which will invoke the api end point, go to the corresponding org/space and then issue a cf push command.

I was able to login and get the metadata of the orgs using below script:

```
import os
from cloudfoundry_client.client import CloudFoundryClient
target_endpoint = 'https://run.api.pivotal.io'
proxy = dict(http=os.environ.get('HTTP_PROXY', ''), https=os.environ.get('HTTPS_PROXY', ''))
client = CloudFoundryClient(target_endpoint, proxy=proxy, skip_verification=True)
client.init_with_user_credentials('abcd@mail.com', 'password')

for organization in client.organizations:
  print organization['metadata']['guid']
```

Please sugggest, also if there are any links do share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using this library? https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-python-client, if not please clarify as your question leaves ambiguity.

The docs state that each entity manager exposes a [generic _create method](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-python-client/blob/master/main/cloudfoundry_client/entities.py#L90), and the [App Entity manager](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-python-client/blob/master/main/cloudfoundry_client/v2/apps.py) does not look to expose a specific push method. You may be able to use the generic _create and pass a dict defining the application.

But I would suggest looking at the [CF-CLI](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli) or [Java Client](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client) which are both maintained by cloud foundry community, and much more well documented.